# Proving the series given by $a_n = (\frac{1}{2})^\frac{n+1}{2}$ if $n$ is odd, $a_n = (\frac{1}{3})^{\frac{n}{2}}$ if $n$ is even, converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So I want to prove the series given by the seqeunce:
$a_n = (\frac{1}{2})^\frac{n+1}{2}$ if $n$ is odd, $a_n = (\frac{1}{3})^{\frac{n}{2}}$ if $n$ is even

converges. I was thinking of comparing it with some series given by the sequence $b_n = 1/2^n + 1/3^n$, but I am not sure if that is legit.

Comment: Note that
$$\left\{\frac{n + 1}{2} : n \in 2\mathbb{N} + 1\right\} = \left\{\frac{n}{2} : n \in 2\mathbb{N}\right\} = \mathbb{N},$$
so you can actually compute your series exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your series is simply
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty (1/2)^{\frac{(2n+1)+1}{2}}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1/3)^{\frac{2n}{2}}$$
Which we can simplify in the form
$$ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1/2)^{n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1/3)^{n}$$
Both of these are convergent, geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the series into two series : $a_n=b_n+c_n$, where
$$b_{2p}=0\text{ and }b_{2p+1}=(\frac12)^{p+1},\ c_{2p}=(\frac13)^p\text{ and } c_{2p+1}=0$$
Both series $\sum b_n$ and $\sum c_n$ converge (they are geometric series filled with useless zeroes), and by using the fact that the set of convergent series is a vectorial space, you can conclude $\sum a_n$ converges.